# React leaflet adding layer that covers whole map and accepts leaflet mouse events

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I have many markers on map with event listeners added to them. I also have a control on map that enables placing other shapes (circles) when map is clicked in the position of a click. The problem now is that clicking on position on the map where marker placed when control is enabled also triggers marker click event. Is there a solution in react-leaflet to add some pane on top of all other panes and layers so events are triggered only on that pane. The key thing here is that pane itself does not have leaflet event handlers, hence can not pass latLng to event callback. It only provides DOM mouseEvent but not LeafletMouseEvent that I need.

Comment: Seems like the overlay is a bit of a hack. Can you modify your marker click event listener? If in drawing mode, don't open popup?

Comment: @teddybeard, for now I am wrapping map container into custom context provider with boolean state and all markers and other layers do not listen to particular events if property is true, but that is cumbersome I guess as adding more and more components will require all of them to rely on that property. That's the reason I am looking for solution to give control to component responsible for placing shapes, so not to enforce other programmers to rely on any properties.